# Low voltage cabling - insulation

Tags: insulation, walls, ceiling

I have a closet that is colder than it should be - it is 2 degrees colder than the bedroom it's connected to.  The closet is 4'x4', and has two exterior walls.  The bedroom is 10'x10', with one exterior wall.  I believe I need to improve the insulation in this closet.  Aside from a [flush mount light fixture](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C4mDT3lWcAAdImQ.jpg), the only other penetration to the drywall is a [Low voltage ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcmzN.jpg) for network cabling - the topic of this post.

The cable is run from the attic, through the top plate of the wall.  I plan on going into the attic and putting some spray foam around the hole in the top plate.  Would it be beneficial, in addition to this, to add some insulation inside the low voltage ring?  If so - how would I go about this?  Is there a product already made for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If there's no heat in this closet, and it has two external walls, and its only heat is whatever bleeds from the bedroom, then it will inevitably be colder than that bedroom. Frankly, a 2 degrees (F?) difference doesn't seem like a lot in this situation.

My reasoning? In cold weather, heat will flow from that closet through those two outside walls and into the great outdoors. The only way heat will **enter** the closet is through the  doors and wall shared with the bedroom, and that will only happen if there's a difference in temperature between the bedroom and the closet.

Insulation will help a bit, but either adding explicit vents between the closet and bedroom, or actually adding a heater to the closet, is the only way you'll significantly reduce that temperature drop.

Comment: I agree, in principle.  If I didn't also have to seal around bathroom fans and such, I wouldn't be fussing with this closet.  But, my wife is cold in her office (that bedroom), so I have to do what I can.  Since I'm already in the attic, I'll be air sealing any penetrations for that closet.  I'm not expecting miracles from insulating one hole - but, since I'm going to be doing this stuff anyway, might as well do a little bit more.